# Jupyter Anaconda: load text file into python

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have Anaconda Python and Jupyter running on Mac.
After typing the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
iris = np.genfromtxt("data/iris.txt",delimiter=None)
```

I get the error: `IOError: data/iris.txt not found.` 
I have tried putting the iris file in the anaconda folder: `Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7`

Answer (score 8):

in Anaconda Python with Jupyter NoteBook you have to give the absolute path with \\ just like given below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("D:\\Nu\\2SEMESTER\\Data Science\\Assignments\\Assignment-1 data\\file.txt")
df     # with this command you can see your file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from pathlib import Path

#file = Path.joinpath('Resources', 'test.txt')
file = Path.cwd() / 'Resources/test.txt'
#file.read_text()

    # Open the file in "read" mode ('r') 
with open(file, 'r') as text:
    textfile = text.read()
    print(textfile)
```

Import the module pathlib.
More information can be found at
https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/

Answer (score 0):

You should not be putting the target file `data/iris.txt` in the Anaconda folder.

Where you invoke Python, is where you should put the file.

```
# Bash
$ cd Downloads/
$ ls
data/

$ cd data/
$ ls
iris.txt

$ cd ..
$ python script.py
```

When Python 'searches' for files it will either search either

- From the directory it was called from (if you use a relative path - one that doesn't start with a `/` character
- Root (if you use absolute paths - one that starts with `/` i.e. Root)

If you want your script to be able to run from any directory use absolute paths in your code

```
import os

base_path = "/path/to/directory/holding/file/"
filename = "iris.txt"
path_to_file = os.path.join(base_path, filename)
fd = open(path_to_file , 'r')
```

It may be better practice to specify this path as a variable so that it can be easily changed in the future. I've included additional (redundant in this case) code to give you an idea of possible functions you can use

Comment: but the error says:Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                               
  File "/Users/ashwinc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1451, in genfromtxt                           
   Doesn't that mean that it is searching in the anaconda folder?

Comment: That's the Traceback. It is going through each step of the program that 'failed', specifying which exact function call raised an error. In this case `npyio.py`. The funcction `npyio.py` has raised the error `IOError:  data/iris.txt not found.` . Or in other words, the Traceback is simply telling you some function is trying to tell you some error.

Comment: Ok. So i used your import os code snippet. In the base_path, I put the directory to a folder in my desktop which has the iris data. Then I copied the rest of your code as you wrote it. I then re ran the import numpy as np import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
iris = np.genfromtxt("data/iris.txt",delimiter=None).   
I still get the same error

Comment: Well no, the above code is an example of how you can use absolute paths. 

Simply put, the path specified as the first argument in the function call `np.genfromtext(...)` must lead to the file **from where you are calling Python** if it is a relative path.

Comment: was the op referring to a jupyter notebook?